# ModelMapper DTO to Entity

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto, modelmapper

I am working on a project for my class. Need to map **DTO** to **Entity** and vice versa. My **DTO** does not have an **Id** field and conversion is happening at **Controller Layer**. 2 other classes are extending my entity, thus @Superbuilder.

My conversion **Entity** -> **DTO** works fine with **ModelMapper**

But **DTO** -> **Entity** does not. ***The commented line*** in **convertToEntity** I thought should work, but nope kept getting the infamous ' *has non-private no-argument constructor* '. Spent hours trying to fix. Decided to go with a simpler solution, though really wanted to make **ModelMapper** work.

If any of you could help me find a fix, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for your time and responses.

======My DTO=====

```
@Value
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserMetaData {

    @NotNull @NotBlank @NotEmpty(message = "First name cannot be empty!")
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    String firstName;
    @NotNull @NotBlank @NotEmpty(message = "Last name cannot be empty!")
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    String lastName;
    @Max(value = 110, message = "Invalid age!") @Min(value = 16, message = "Must be older than 16!")
    @JsonProperty("age")
    int age;
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("privilege")
    Privilege privilege;
    //@NotNull
    @JsonProperty("alias")
    String alias;
    //@Singular
    @JsonProperty("groups")
    Set<Group> groups;


}
```

=====My Entity=====

```
@Document(collection = "Users")
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
public class Member implements User {

@Id
protected final UUID id;
protected final String firstName;
protected final String lastName;
protected final int age;
@Builder.Default
protected final Privilege privilege = NONE;
protected String alias;
protected Set<Group> groups;

protected Set<Group> addGroup(Group group) {
    this.groups.add(group);
    return this.groups;
}
```

}

=====Bean for ModelMapper=====

```
 @Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
            .setFieldAccessLevel(org.modelmapper.config.Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
    return modelMapper;
}
```

=====Converters=====

```
 private UserMetaData convertToDTO(Member member) {
    return modelMapper.map(member, UserMetaData.UserMetaDataBuilder.class)
            .build();
}

private Member convertToEntity(UserMetaData dto) {
//        return modelMapper.map(dto, Member.MemberBuilder.class).id(UUID.randomUUID()).build();
    return Member.builder()
            .id(UUID.randomUUID())
            .firstName(dto.getFirstName())
            .lastName(dto.getLastName())
            .age(dto.getAge())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DTO` class is using `@Builder` while your `Entity` class is using `@SuperBuilder`. 
There are difference between `@Builder` and `@SuperBuilder`. Look at `target` files after you compiled project:

- `@Builder` will create a static class named `DTOBuilder` and it has a public constructor

```java
public class DTO {
    //...
    public static class DTOBuilder {
         public DTOBuilder() {
         }
    }
}
```

- `@SuperBuilder` will create a `public abstract class EntityBuilder` and a `private implemented class EntityBuilderImpl` with a `private constructor`

```java
public class Entity {
     //...
     public abstract static class EntityBuilder<...> {
     }
     //...
     private static final class EntityBuilderImpl extends EntityBuilder {
            private EntityBuilderImpl() {
            }
     }
}
```

So, `ModelMapper` requires target class should be `public class` and `public contructor`. That's why you can not map to `EntityBuilder` but it's ok with `DTOBuilder`.

**Solution** is, instead of mapping to `EntityBuilder`, you should map to Entity directly.
NOTE that your entity must have `No Args Constructor`

Add `@NoArgsConstructor` into your Entity and convert from your DTO to Entity class instead of EntityBuilder

```java
//...
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Member implements User {
//...
}

private Member convertToEntity(UserMetaData dto) {
    return modelMapper.map(dto, Member.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your response. The thing is my Entity has final fields.